# Remove #/ from path if index page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I made an embedded widget in a modal window. To insert it in any website.

In this widget I cahnge hash through HashRouter.

And when I close the modal window I want to remove "#/" from url.

I decided to do it through (or is there another way?)

`window.history.replaceState(null, null, document.location.href.split('#')[0])`

But **I don’t understand at what point should I call this** (after triggering the URL changes back to `#/`)

The latter tried in the Child component, in which the update is fired last, to call on `componentDidUpdate`.

Ierarchy:

index.js -> ParentComponent -> ChildComponent

Parent

```
render() {
  return (
    <HashRouter>
      <ChildComponent />
    </HashRouter>
  );
}
```

Child

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  if (!location.hash.includes('search')) {
    window.history
        .replaceState(null, null, document.location.href.split('#')[0]);
  }
}
```

Comment: why don't you use BrowserRouter instead

Comment: It is  an embedded widget and I must not change url on not my website.
So I need to use hash. not full path

Answer (score 0):

You can as well use `document.location.href.replace('#/', '')` to remove the characters.

Comment: The question is when I can call changeUrl method
And you've answered on another question: "How get full href without hash?"